# SQL Query on reservation checking

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, Facility and Reservation tables.

Facility table contains,

- FacilityID
- Type
- Name
- Availability

Reservation table,

- ID
- MemberID
- FacilityID
- Check-in date
- Check-in time

Here is my query which it only return the reserved details. How can i make the query to return those unreserved facility details?

```
SELECT Facility.[Facility Name], Facility.[Facility Type] 
FROM Facility INNER JOIN Reservation on Facility.FacilityID = Reservation.FacilityID
WHERE Reservation.FacilityID = (
    SELECT FacilityID 
    FROM Reservation 
    WHERE MemberID = '" & txtMemberID.Text & "' 
    AND [Check-in date] ='" & lstDate.SelectedItem.ToString & "')
```

Comment: It just for assignment purpose which I tried many ways and method but still can't get the result i wanted.

Comment: so how do we know it's unreserved?

Comment: This is the thing that I can't figure out. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a LEFT OUTER JOIN and an IS NULL to only return rows without a record in the Reservation table.

The following query would return all Facilities that do not have a match in the Reservation table on FacilityID, MemberID and Check-In date. You can remove the MemberID and Check-In Date portions if you want to see if they have a Reservation for any member and any check-in date

```
SELECT Facility.[Facility Name], Facility.[Facility Type] 
FROM Facility 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Reservation on Facility.FacilityID = Reservation.FacilityID
    AND MemberID = '" & txtMemberID.Text & "' // pull in based on certain member
    AND [Check-in date] ='" & lstDate.SelectedItem.ToString & "') // pull in based on certain date
WHERE Reservation.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: So it will return all Facilities that are **not** reserved by a particular member? Is this what's required>

Comment: @PM77-1 yes, since that's what he asked for. If member is not a constraint it can be removed.

Comment: Hopefully OP clarifies his/her requirements.

Comment: I have another question,

how can I filter those reserved and only display unreserved based on the type and availability?

I tried to modified urs but it still gave me all the available facility without filtering them.

Found it. Miss look the where clause.